# not able to print the value one by one when iterating through for loop

Tags: java, string, loops

```java
public void verifyPattenData() {            
    beans = new HealthDataBeans();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                      
        System.out.println("aaaaaa" +
            ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getProperty("value").toString()
        );
    }
}
```

getting Output like- [350,218,344]
data type is - string

But I need to print the value in the below format -

350
218
344

please help me on this if anyone can provide the solution

Comment: where is the rest of your code?!  when you use for loop, you have to get values with the i  int that you declared

Comment: Why do you use a loop since you do not use the `i` inside the loop ? How does your output does not contains "aaaaaa" ? How does your output is one line when you print 3 lines ?

Comment: What is the datatype of `ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getProperty("value")` ?

Comment: data type is string

Comment: In that case, such a `String` is already `[350,218,344]` which I find weird. It seems to me that `ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getProperty("value")` returns a `List` instead.

Comment: ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getProperty("value").toString()));
                                                 
        for(int j = 0; j < namesList.size(); j++)
        {
           System.out.println("->>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+namesList.get(j));
          }

when using the above code getting  output like- ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>[219,284,317]



can you help me on this to get output like 

350
218
344

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove brackets and split the string by comma and/or spaces getting the array of String, print each element as needed:

```java
String output = ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getProperty("value").toString();
System.out.println("aaaaaa: " + String.join("\n", 
    output.replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "") // remove brackets
          .split(",\\s*")              // get array of strings
));
```

2. Use `replaceAll` to replace commas followed by spaces with `"\n"`:

```java
System.out.println("aaaaaa: " + output
    .replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")
    .replaceAll(",\\s*", "\n")
);
```

Output in both cases:

```
aaaaaa: 350
218
344
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```java
public void verifyPattenData() {            
    beans = new HealthDataBeans();

    List<String> values = ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getProperty("value");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {                      
        System.out.println(values.get(i));
    }
}
```